# source insight like free source code browser and editor in windows

Tags: windows, source-insight

can  anyone suggest me  free source code browser (c/c++ )and editor in windows like source insight?

Comment: You get what you pay for. Source Insight is a bargain http://www.sourceinsight.com/buyit.html. I am _not_ a vendor -- just a satisfied customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Express edition is free...

[c/c++ version](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/)

It is a full compiler so if you don't need to compile code, it might be a little overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Source Navigator
http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Understand from SCI tools is good one. 
http://www.scitools.com/products/understand/

Comment: Understand is good but not free http://www.scitools.com/store/. Sometimes have to pay for good tools.